# getting pointer to a vector C++

Tags: c++, vector

this is my second basic question on pointers.
I am calling a function exposed in DLL..

A vector is being declared and populated with values inside that function being called.

I need to loop through the vector and access its values from the calling function.

```
int calling_function()
{
int* vectorSize;
string input = "someValue";
vector<customObjects> *v;// do i need a pointer to a vector here?

void function_being_called(input,v,&vectorSize);

//need to access the vector here...

}

void function_being_called(string input, void *returnValue, int* vectorSize)
{
vector<customObjects> v;
v.push_back(myObj);

*vectorSize= v.size();

*returnValue = ? // how to pass vector to the calling function through this parameter pointer variable

return;
}
```

Comment: Your vectorSize pointer is uninitialized. Also it's unnecessary.

Comment: Yuck. An `int` for vectorSize?! Use `std::size_t` (some folk even frown on that, saying you ought to use `std::vector<>::size_type` since the standard does not specify that should be the same as `std::size_t`), better still ditch it altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two options. First, pass the vector as a reference:

```
string input = "someValue";
vector<customObjects> v;
function_being_called(input, v);

void function_being_called(string input, vector<customObjects> &v)
{
 // Whatever
}
```

Or, if you're using C++11 just return  a `vector` and let the move constructor take care of it:

```
string input = "someValue";
vector<customObjects> v =  function_being_called(input);

vector<customObjects> function_being_called(string input)
{
  vector<customObjects> v;

 // Whatever

  return v;
}
```

Comment: thanks. i liked the second solution because i dont want to remove the declaration from the called function just to be sure as a beginner.

Answer (score 2):

It should be like this:

```
int calling_function()
{
  string input = "someValue";
  vector<customObjects> v;

  function_being_called(input,&v);

  // access the vector here...

}

void function_being_called(string input, vector<customObjects>* v)
{
  v->push_back(myObj);
}
```

Comment: I prefer that style as it signals to the caller that the vector might be modified. But immensely personal I know.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: personally I usually prefer pointers for out-parameters, because it's more clear.  Unfortunately C++ has no builtin way to say `[out]` like some languages do.  Yes, you could pass nullptr, but oh well, I still find call sites much more obvious this way.  A matter of taste, certainly.  Some coding conventions require this--I think including Google's.